# jpanel doesn't match with jdesktop pane when resizing

Tags: java, swing, mdi, jdesktoppane

I had an application in Java have a jdesktop pane with 3 normal panels. The problem occurs when I resize the MDI window - the three panels don't match with the MDI window. How can I fix this knowing that I'm using netbeans IDE?

Comment: Please put your research first

Comment: Maybe have you got some code or something useful to work with?

Answer (score 1):

> a jdesktop pane with 3 normal panels.

A `JDesktopPane` is not designed to be used with "normal panels".

Instead you add a `JInternalFrame` to the desktop pane. When the internal frames are maximized they will match the desktop pane size.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Desktop Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html) for more information and working examples.